# Need to get city and state by giving zip code in .Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Any one please help me to get city and state by giving Zip code,for example: i have usps api i got it from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16041/United-States-Postal-Service-USPS-Web-Tools-Wrappe   i download the project from this link and run the solution file and build the solution after that i have max usps dll from that.by refer that dll to my visual studio project i only get vadiateAddress(Address) function but it also have getcitystate function by passing zip code for example:

```
        Dim m As New USPSManager("739MEGSO2602", True)
        Dim a As MAX.USPS.Address = m.GetCityState(Zip)
        Dim citys As String = a.City
        Dim states As String = a.State
```

to get city and state by giving zip code when i pass zip code it returns empty string...Any one please help me to resolve this....?

thanks in Advance..

Comment: Why don't you ask the author?